# SQL table for friends, mutual friends, friends friends etc

Tags: sql

I was wondering what the easiest method would be for me in the future to make queries both effective and less complex.

Should I save a two way relationship like

from_id=1, to_id=2
from_id=2, to_id=1

or just create one unique row

from_id=1, to_id=2

any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the entire structure of your table, and some examples of queries? You know, in order to have some idea how to optimize your database, we need some more info than the general description you gave us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to go for two way relationship. It's flexible ans it's only extra work while `insert`ing and `delete`ing the records.

The benefits that I see is:

- To get all friend of a person all you need to do is `where from_id=userid` instead of `where from_id=userid or to_id=userid` that later is expensive.
- you can keep extra metadata in forward and reverse relationship. Let's say you have a case like `userA is friend of userB while userB does not approves the relationship`. To do this you may have an extra `isApproved` and set it `true` for `from_id=userA, to_id=userB` and false for `from_id=userB, to_id=userA` -- this will allow further cheap `sort` and `select`.
   The effect in single row will be a little trickier.

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/07/selecting-friends/ contains an in-depth discussion of this topic. The conclusion is as you say- two rows per relation is much easier to query for only a small penalty to maintain.

Comment: @Alexander you may well mark this answer as correct by clicking one the uptick mark next to the answer and give a up-vote by clicking on up arrow, if you liked this answer.